# Trying to find a shapefile on Hawaii volcano locations

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa, land

I have downloaded a shapefile of volcanoes all over the world, but when zoomed in to Hawaii, not all of Hawaii's volcanoes are displayed. I have been searching but I can't seem to find a shapefile of all of the Hawaiian volcanoes or even the Hawaiian-Emperor chain.

Comment: Can you add where you downloaded yours from. Maybe that helps bringing idea to others or doing duplicate work.

Comment: esri featureserver api that can be scraped into .shp/.geojson/etc. but i'm not sure if this is just for the island or the entire state: http://geodata.hawaii.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Hazards/MapServer

Comment: also, is this site's coverage not definitive? i would think they would have it all: https://volcanoes.usgs.gov/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following sources in the past for volcano data:

- [Global Volcano Locations Database](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/global-volcano-locations-database) from data.gov
- [Volcano - Population Exposure Index(GVM)](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/a60ac839-920d-435a-bf7d-25855602699d)  from humdata.org

Unfortunately I do not know if the coverage would be sufficient for your purposes.